Full rotating property of quaternionic polynomial
Does a quaternionic polynomial $Q\in\mathbb{H}[t]$ exist with the property that for any quaternionic imaginary unit $I \in \mathbb{S}=\{ q\in\mathbb{H} \mid q^2=-1 \}$ it holds $$Q(I)\notin\mathbb{C}_I,$$
where $\mathbb{C}_I=span(1,I)$? 
With quaternionic polynomial I mean something of the form $\sum q^la_l$, $a_l\in\mathbb{H}$.
For constant polynomials it does not exist and I am quite confident that for linear polynomials it does not exist as well.
Thank you for your help.

Every polynomial evaluated on a unit it the same as some "linear" polynomial evaluated on that unit because $q^2 = -1$. So the question reduces to the "linear" polynomial case.

Yes, you are definitely right. Thank you!

@NicholasTodoroff do you have any idea about how to prove the linear case?

Maybe I don't understand your definition of $\mathbb C_I$, but isn't that just $\mathbb H$?

@Kimball, no it is a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{H}$, a copy of complex numbers inside quaternions.

Ah, sorry, I misread and I thought $I$ was the set of square roots of $-1$, not a fixed one.

BTW, does this problem come from something else?

@coiso the question arises from factorization of polynomials in dual quaternions. I found that the zeroes of a dual quaternionic polynomial are associated to the zeroes of a quaternionic polynomial and when it has an entire sphere of zeroes, I could recover the original zero if the question I made have positive answer. Btw, thank you for your answer, even if I don't understand it

For me, the quaternions are formal sums of scalars and 3D vectors, $\Bbb H=\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R^3$. The quaternion product of 3D vectors has scalar and vector parts given by $\mathbf{uv}=-\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}$. In particular:

the sqrts of $+1$ are $S^0=\{\pm1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$,
the sqrts of $-1$ are $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$;,
quaternions commute ($pq=qp$) iff they have parallel vector part,
they anticommute ($qp=-pq$) iff they are perpendicular vectors.

The scalar and vector parts of a quaternion are also called the real and imaginary parts.
Suppose we have a quaternion function $Q(t)=a_0+ta_1+t^2a_2+\cdots$. Note that if $\mathbf{t}\in S^2$ is a sqrt of $-1$ then this evaluates to
$$Q(\mathbf{t})=(a_0-a_2+a_4-\cdots)+\mathbf{t}(a_1-a_3+a_5-\cdots)=A+\mathbf{t}B,$$
so it suffices to consider your question for functions of the form $Q(\mathbf{t})=A+\mathbf{t}B$. Set
$$ \mathbf{a}={\rm Im}\,A, \quad \mathbf{b}={\rm Im}\,B,\quad\theta=\angle\mathbf{ab}. $$
WLOG $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\ne\mathbf{0}$ and $0<\theta<\pi$. Then
$$A+\mathbf{t}B\in\mathbb{R}[{\bf t}]\iff \mathbf{a}+\mathbf{tb}\in\mathbb{R}[{\bf t}]\iff{\bf a}_\perp+{\bf tb}_\perp={\bf 0},$$ where ${\bf a}_\perp,{\bf b}_\perp$ are the perpendicular components of ${\bf a},{\bf b}$ with respect to ${\bf t}$. WLOG ${\bf a}_\perp,{\bf b}_\perp\ne{\bf 0}$. Define magnitudes $a=\|{\bf a}\|,b=\|{\bf b}\|$ and unknowns $\alpha=\angle{\bf ta},\beta=\angle{\bf tb}$. Note $\alpha,\beta$ determine ${\bf t}$ up to reflection across the plane ${\rm span}\{{\bf a},{\bf b}\}$ (which doesn't affect the truth-value of ${\bf a}+{\bf tb}\in{\Bbb R}[{\bf t}]$). Define an orthonormal basis $\{{\bf u},{\bf v},{\bf w}\}$ with ${\bf v}:={\bf t}$ and ${\bf a}\in{\rm span}\{{\bf u},{\bf v}\},{\bf b}\in{\rm span}\{{\bf v},{\bf w}\}$. More precisely,
$$ \begin{cases}
{\bf a} = a\,\bigl(\sin\alpha\,{\bf u}+\cos\alpha\,{\bf v}\bigr), \\[3pt]
{\bf b} = b\,\bigl(\sin\beta\,{\bf w}+\sin\beta\,{\bf v}\bigr).
\end{cases} $$
Then our requirements are equivalent to
$$ \begin{cases}
{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}=ab\cos\theta \\[3pt]
{\bf a}_\perp=-{\bf v\,b}_\perp
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
 \cos\alpha\,\cos\beta=\cos\theta \\[3pt]
 a\sin\alpha = b\sin\beta
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
 \cos\beta=\cos\theta\,\sec\alpha \\[3pt]
 \sin\beta=\frac{a}{b}\sin\alpha
\end{cases} $$
This has a solution for $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ iff the Pythagorean identity holds:
$$\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta=1 \iff (\cos\theta\sec\alpha)^2+(\tfrac{a}{b}\sin\alpha)^2=1. $$
Setting $r=\sin^2\alpha$ and clearing denominators, this is
$$ \cos^2\theta+\bigl(\tfrac{a}{b}\bigr)^2r(1-r)=1-r. $$
This is quadratic in $r$, and has a solution $r\in(0,1)$ by applying IVT with $r=0,1$.
The value $0<r<1$ determines $\alpha$, hence $\beta$, hence ${\bf t}$ for which $Q({\bf t})\in{\Bbb R}[{\bf t}]$.
